# Avoiding Netty copies from InputStream

Tags: netty

Betty has a wonderful flexible abstraction layer that is used to represent buffers for reading and writing that can operate very well with NIO. In Netty 4 this is the ByteBuf class and in Netty 3 this is the ChannelBuffer.

I am dealing with a library (JDBC) that returns an InputStream for a piece of data as part of an in-house storage engine. The current code copies this to an intermediate byte array and builds the ChannelBuffer around this byte array before giving it to Netty to process. I am trying to reduce the number of unnecessary copies happening in this stack and would love to pass the InputStream directly to Netty with no intermediate copy so that Netty can write the contents of the InputStream directly to the socket without allocating any large intermediate object. Is there any facility in Netty that allows creating a read-only ChannelBuffer/ByteBuf from an InputStream that doesn't invoke a full-copy of the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is the `ChunkedWriteHandler` and `ChunkedStream` ?